# How can I turn off the feature that notifies me via e-mail of comments on my posts?

Tags: support

I get an e-mail notification whenever someone has commented on my posts. How do I turn this feature off?  I do not find reminders helpful -- maybe when I become gaga, but that is not now.

Also, right now, at the top of my screen is a little red 9 indicating that there are 9 comments that I have, according to the Robo-Nanny, not paid sufficient respect to.  Some of these comments are months old.  I have read them.  I do not want to be reminded to read them again.  What do I do to make the Robo-Nanny stop nagging me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit the 'mark all read' message at the top of the drop down menu in the top of the screen.
This will get rid of the red marker but not the e-mails, I think.

But as I have not had reminder e-mails in a long time, getting rid of the marker might also stop the mails.

(I converted a comment into an answer when it got a 'this works' reply.)